# Why the interface field access in the GO language program given in details works?

Tags: go, interface

I have defined 2 interfaces {Main, Sub} and a structure HumanStruct in the code in the following link. I know why s1.(Main).Title() works.But I want to know why m.(Sub).Name() works. Here 'm' is variable of interface Main type. This Main interface has no field 'Sub'. Then how it works?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Main interface {
    Title() string
}

type Sub interface {
    Main
    Name() string
}

type HumanStruct struct {
    name  string
    title string
}

func (hs HumanStruct) Name() string {
    return hs.name
}

func (hs HumanStruct) Title() string {
    return hs.title
}

func main() {
    h := HumanStruct{name: "John", title: "Kings"}

    var m Main
    m = h

    var s1 Sub
    s1 = h

    fmt.Println("From main: ", m.(Sub).Name())
    fmt.Println("From sub:  ", s1.(Main).Title())
}
```

Comment: You naming of the interface suggests you think of subclasses or inheritance. Stop this now and forever. Thinking along this concepts will not help you programming in Go. It really won't. If you model your problems with this state of mind you will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the type assertion expression `m.(Sub)` is of type `Sub`.  Interface `Sub` has a `Name()` method which you can call.

The type assertion of `m` to `Sub` succeeds because the value in `m` is a `HumanStruct` and that type satisfies the `Sub` interface.